# Whats the easiest way to pad an alphabet index both sides with zeroes?

Tags: python, padding

I need a dataset encoding the english language in the following format:

`A = (1000000000000000000000000)`
`B = (0100000000000000000000000)` 
And so on...

Whats the easiest way to pad letter indexes with zeroes in Python?

Ive so far tried this:

```
alphabet = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

        for letter_index in range(len(alphabet)):
            print( '{0} = ({1})'.format(alphabet[letter_index], str(letter_index).rjust(letter_index).ljust(26-letter_index)))
```

But my output is like this:

```
A = (0                         )
B = (1                        )
C = ( 2                      )
D = (  3                    )
E = (   4                  )
F = (    5                )
G = (     6              )
H = (      7            )
I = (       8          )
J = (        9        )
K = (        10      )
L = (         11    )
M = (          12  )
N = (           13)
O = (            14)
P = (             15)
Q = (              16)
R = (               17)
S = (                18)
T = (                 19)
U = (                  20)
V = (                   21)
W = (                    22)
X = (                     23)
Y = (                      24)
Z = (                       25)
```

And finally, if i want to comma separate the numbers in my dataset, what is the easiest way to do that?
For example:
`A = (1,0,0...)`

Comment: What is the expected output? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: What do u mean? The expected output is written there. 
I will label it so.

Comment: Do you mean something like `','.join(list('1000000000000000000000000'))` Your question is not clear to me at all.

Comment: @dawg -- You don't even need the call to `list` in there -- Strings are iterable too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will give you the output you desire:

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
zero25 = "0" * 25
for idx in range (len (alpha)):
    print "%s = (%s1%s)" % (alpha[idx], zero25[:idx], zero25[:25-idx])
```

Specifically, the output is:

```
A = (10000000000000000000000000)
B = (01000000000000000000000000)
C = (00100000000000000000000000)
D = (00010000000000000000000000)
E = (00001000000000000000000000)
F = (00000100000000000000000000)
G = (00000010000000000000000000)
H = (00000001000000000000000000)
I = (00000000100000000000000000)
J = (00000000010000000000000000)
K = (00000000001000000000000000)
L = (00000000000100000000000000)
M = (00000000000010000000000000)
N = (00000000000001000000000000)
O = (00000000000000100000000000)
P = (00000000000000010000000000)
Q = (00000000000000001000000000)
R = (00000000000000000100000000)
S = (00000000000000000010000000)
T = (00000000000000000001000000)
U = (00000000000000000000100000)
V = (00000000000000000000010000)
W = (00000000000000000000001000)
X = (00000000000000000000000100)
Y = (00000000000000000000000010)
Z = (00000000000000000000000001)
```

If you want them separated by commas, this will do the trick:

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
zero25 = "0," * 25

print "%s = (1,%s)" % (alpha[0], zero25[:49])
for idx in range (1, len (alpha)):
    print "%s = (%s,1%s)" % (alpha[idx], zero25[:idx*2-1], zero25[idx*2-1:-1])
```

outputting:

```
A = (1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
B = (0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
C = (0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
D = (0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
E = (0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
F = (0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
G = (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
H = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
I = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
J = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
K = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
L = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
M = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
N = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
O = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
P = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Q = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
R = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
S = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
T = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
U = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
V = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
W = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
X = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
Y = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
Z = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something akin to this:

```
>>> '{:0<26}'.format('1'.zfill(1))
'10000000000000000000000000'
>>> '{:0<26}'.format('1'.zfill(2))
'01000000000000000000000000'
```

A complete example would be something like this:

```
>>> c = 'A'
>>> '{} = ({:0<26})'.format(c, '1'.zfill(ord(c)-ord('A')+1))
'A = (10000000000000000000000000)'
>>> c = 'B'
>>> '{} = ({:0<26})'.format(c, '1'.zfill(ord(c)-ord('A')+1))
'B = (01000000000000000000000000)'
>>> c = 'C'
>>> '{} = ({:0<26})'.format(c, '1'.zfill(ord(c)-ord('A')+1))
'C = (00100000000000000000000000)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for i in range(26):
...   print "{} = ({}1{})".format(chr(i+65),'0'*i,'0'*(25-i))
... 
A = (10000000000000000000000000)
B = (01000000000000000000000000)
C = (00100000000000000000000000)
D = (00010000000000000000000000)
E = (00001000000000000000000000)
F = (00000100000000000000000000)
G = (00000010000000000000000000)
H = (00000001000000000000000000)
I = (00000000100000000000000000)
J = (00000000010000000000000000)
K = (00000000001000000000000000)
L = (00000000000100000000000000)
M = (00000000000010000000000000)
N = (00000000000001000000000000)
O = (00000000000000100000000000)
P = (00000000000000010000000000)
Q = (00000000000000001000000000)
R = (00000000000000000100000000)
S = (00000000000000000010000000)
T = (00000000000000000001000000)
U = (00000000000000000000100000)
V = (00000000000000000000010000)
W = (00000000000000000000001000)
X = (00000000000000000000000100)
Y = (00000000000000000000000010)
Z = (00000000000000000000000001)
```